# First thing to know about improving website layout and design

Tags: .net, layout, sitedesign

I am building an internal, data-heavy website for my company on the Microsoft stack (ASP.NET 2.0/C#/SQL Server).  Lately I have been trying to improve the layout and design of this site, partly because I want it to look good for my employers, but mostly because I want to learn about page layout and design.

My question is, what is the first thing I should know about improving the layout and design of pages in a data-intensive (e.g. lots of large grids, validation, minimal navigation, etc.) website.  I really have no idea where to begin.

Comment: Totally off topic, but why .Net 2.0?  .Net 3.5 supports LINQ.  If this is a data heavy website, you may love using LINQ as opposed to traditional SQL queries.

Comment: For what it's worth, you may have better luck with this question on doctype.com.

Comment: Because my corporate servers have not upgraded to it yet, though it is planned for sometime in the next year.

Comment: Fair enough.  I once worked at a bank whose "cutting edge" technology was at least 5 years old.  And that was reserved only for new, low security development :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [Don't Make Me Think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0789723107).

Comment: Fantastic usability book, I also suggest that the op for this question give SERIOUS consideration to usability testing with mockups.

Comment: I found it rather simple. I come from a background of e-commerce usability optimization, and I'll say if you have any experience in this field, this book is not going to make you any smarter.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I constantly learn about myself.

I'm not sure what to say exactly.  But I can recommend a good source... Alistapart.com.  In particular their "design" section of articles are good and may provide just what you need...

http://www.alistapart.com/topics/design/

They talk about designs, layouts, and in many of their articles -- the HTML & CSS required to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

I consistently refer to this article when asked this question. This is by far the most to-the-point summary you can read:

http://wefunction.com/2009/04/quality-within-web-design/

The first 4 points I believe would apply to you the most. Here's a quick synopsis:

1. Spacing
2. Pixel Perfect Detail
3. Well thought out Typography
4. Organization of Elements
5. Restraint & Subtlety
6. Using Colour to it’s Full Potential
7. Doing something Nobody else has done

Comment: There is one thing I disagree with, and that's their examples under the  "Doing something Nobody else has done" section.  Funky navigation is rarely a good idea for usability.  And in my opinion usability really should be the primary concern.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothesize. Test. Reiterate. Iterative testing is the most important thing you can do because it gives you objective evidence as to what actually works. If you were doing an external website, you would have an analytics package that you could use for this. With an internal website, pull some of your colleagues in from the hallway and ask them to use the new layout while you observe them. You'll learn a lot by watching your users and you can make changes based on what you learn.

Answer (score 0):

Well the FIRST thing for web is the browser box model.